# Can you breed new gold roses with existing gold roses on Animal Crossing New Horizons?

Tags: animal-crossing-new-horizons

I've successfully bred gold roses from black roses on my island. I want to know if it is possible for me to use two or four gold roses to breed more gold roses in the diamond formation.

If not do I just continue to water my black roses with my gold watering can to produce more?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Golden roses won't clone or breed with another golden rose. According to [the animal crossing fandom wiki](https://animalcrossing.fandom.com/wiki/Flower/New_Horizons_mechanics):

> While a golden rose cannot clone or breed with another golden rose, it can be used as a partner to another rose. For this purpose, it is considered to have a 'rryywwbb' genotype.

So yes, if you want more, you'll have to continue to water your black roses with the gold watering can.